# My MYMODULE_config_preprocess_node(&$variables) is not displaying my variables

Tags: theming

I have 2 modules both implementing the same hook: hook_preprocess_node()

What I do is basically the same in both:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $stuff_to_display = $variables['myfield'];
    $output = '';

$variables['my_stuff'] = $output;

}
```

When I use a debug function I can see my variable (my_stuff) there but is not rendering on the page

While is working for the first module is not working for the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're halfway there! The thing is that it isn't enough just to set the variable in the preprocess function, now you have to go one step further and output it in your tlp.php template file.

So, find the correct template file in your theme that you want to use (is it a general node.tpl.php one or a one for a specific content type like node--article.tpl.php), and edit it to actually output the variable you've set.

So, in the tpl.php file you're using, you should have something like:

```
<?php print $my_stuff; ?>
```

Otherwise, you've set the variable, but never display it.  Does that make sense?  Is that what's going on in your case?

Comment: You're right. The variable was there in the theme but there was a conditional in the theme that I was not aware of. Thanls Boriana